# How isolation level of MySQL/InnoDB is implemented?

Tags: c++, mysql, innodb

I've been studying how Multiversion 2PL (MV2PL) scheme of InnoDB is preventing the non-repeatable anomaly of MySQL.

By the implementation method of MV2PL, the non-repeatable anomaly is prevented by default due to the versioning technique (can read the older version even the row is modified and committed by other transaction).

However, when I change the isolation level to READ COMMITTED, as you know, the non-repeatable is not prevented. That is, the same SELECT query in the same period transaction might not get an identical result.

Here's the question. The basic implementation of MV2PL prevents the anomaly, but how can the non-repeatable read anomaly happen when I downgrade the isolation level to READ COMMITTED?

Is there any if-else statement in InnoDB source code filtering those isolation levels?

Comment: *"but how can the non-repeatable read anomaly happen when I downgrade the isolation level to READ COMMITTED?"* Does the explainment in the MySQL manual help for you research? [READ COMMITTED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_read-committed) and [Consistent Nonlocking Reads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html)

Comment: `REPEATABLE READ` and `READ COMMITTED` are two of the 4 modes available in InnoDB.

Comment: Thank you so much Raymond. I now understand how isolation level works at multi-versioning schemes. The article helped me a lot. Thanks!